# Checking if all bits in k between 1 to n are set

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation

I was reading one question on the blog and the solution of the question was to check whether 1 to n bits in 'k' are set or not.

For ex.

- k = 3 and n = 2; then "True" since 1st and 2nd bit are set in k
- k = 3 and n = 3; then "False" since 3rd bit in k is not set

The solution as provided by the author is:

```
    if (((1 << (n-1)) ^ (k & ((1 << n)-1))) == ((1 << (n-1))-1))
        std::cout<<"true"<<std::endl; 
    else 
        std::cout<<"false"<<std::endl;
```

I am not sure what's going on here.
Could someone please help me understand this?

Comment: What don't you understand here?  The syntax?  The maths?  Why it works?

Comment: Mainly how the expression, for finding whether all the bits are set or not, is working.

Comment: Ok.  Have you tried working it through an example by hand?  These Wikipedia articles will probably be useful: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmask.

Comment: Yes. For I tried for k = 3 and n =2, I ended up getting 01 == 01 which is true. What I am confused about is why is sometimes he is doing `(1<<(n-1))` and sometimes `(1 << n) -1`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you draw out the binary representations on pen and paper, you'll see that `(1 << (n-1))` always sets a single bit to 1 (the `n`-th bit), whereas `(1 << n) - 1` sets the first `n` bits.

These are [bitmasks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitmask); they're being used to manipulate certain sections of the input (`k`) via bitwise operations (`&`, `|` and `^`).

**Note**

I think the example is needlessly complicated.  This should be sufficient:

```
if ((k & ((1 << n) - 1)) == ((1 << n) - 1))
    ...
```

Or to make it even cleaner:

```
unsigned int mask = (1 << n) - 1;
if ((k & mask) == mask)
   ...
```

(assuming that `k` is of type `unsigned int`).

Comment: Thanks for rewriting the expression to something sane, the original looked too much like code obfuscation for my taste.

Comment: Even simpler: `if (!((k + 1) & ((1 << n) - 1)))`